# How to iterate over the properties of an object in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm debuging an complex calculation object in my project, and I'd like to show its various and many properties in a textbox, to make my tests easier.

Can I do something like

```
for each p as someKindOfProperty in MyObject1
  debug.print(p.name & " - " & debug.print p.value)
  textbox1.text = textbox1.text & vbcrlf & p.name & " - " & p.value
next
```

???

How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Dim props As PropertyInfo() = GetType(Color).GetProperties(BindingFlags.[Static] Or BindingFlags.[Public])

For Each prop As PropertyInfo In props
    Dim o As Object = prop.GetValue(Nothing, Nothing)
    If o IsNot Nothing Then
        textbox1.Text = Textbox1.text + Constants.vbcrlf + prop.Name + " - " + o.ToString()
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Yeah, reflection is your friend here.